# Where to find structure of objects that I can access in PHP snippets added to different parts of UI?

Tags: 7, views

In views I can add PHP snippets for custom validation or when I want to provide default value for contextual filter. It is telling me that I can use $view or $argument - but where is documentation of these objects? Where can I read what are my possibilities in these areas (or how check this, by using debugger for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and use the dpm function to check it out.
You can check the whole list of devel functions at http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html

Comment: I installed devel module, and put this code to (PHP custom code) action in Rules: "dpm($site);" yet when action happens - it doesn't show anything, so I still doesn't know what in $site variable is at the moment of execution :/ .

Comment: did you try print dpm($site);

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't work. I tried drupal_set_message() to be sure that action triggers and it works. Tried also "kpr($site);" without effect :/ .

Comment: I don't know why but after installing Drupal again it now works. Thanks!